# Retrieve frames from gif in android kotlin/java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmap, png

I'm trying to split a gif into frames of that gif that could be later on used in a recyclerview to display. I can't find any library or any other resource for this.

I have tried to find some libraries for it but wasn't able to find any. I saw a code but they used ImageIO but I can't find ImageIO when I'm coding in kotlin.

Comment: Perhaps you can use this to get all the frames as bitmaps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60887172/10514633

Once you have all the bitmaps you can add them to your RecyclerView.

Comment: The `javax.imageio` package that contains `ImageIO` isn't available on Android (regardless of Java or Kotlin).

Comment: Thank you. Glide help to get all the frames from the gif.